# Can git flow support multiple on-going releases?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm wondering if/how git flow supports multiple on-going releases. Do I have to wait release-1.0 branch to be branched from DEV branch (which means all features are ready for release-1.0) before I start creating feature branches for the release-1.1? What if I also need to start release-1.1 and release-2.0 development in parallel?
To my understanding, a release branch will only be created when all the features for this release have been merged into DEV branch through PRs. I'm not exactly sure how concurrent releases can be handled in git-flow. I would assume git-flow should be mature enough to handle concurrent releases. But can't figure out how to do it. Your thoughts and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I prefer plain git with "master" as main development branch and the release branches (or single "production" branch) as stuff to deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if/how git flow supports multiple on-going releases.

git-flow does not support 2 releases branches at the same time yet.

> would assume git-flow should be mature enough to handle concurrent releases. But can't figure out how to do it. Your thoughts and suggestions are much appreciated!

Check [this issue in the official gitflow project on github](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/3) for workarounds to use 2 release branches at the same time.